# Why python print(09) give SyntaxError: invalid token but not print(07)?

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is version of Python installed on my system.

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 16 2017, 17:29:19) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Somehow, 08, 09 is not understand at 8, 9. But other number work

```
>>> print(02)
2
>>> print(09)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(09)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> print(08)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(08)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> print(07)
7
```

Not only print, but datetime.date also throw SyntaxError

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2017,11,09)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    datetime.date(2017,11,09)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> datetime.date(2017,11,04)
datetime.date(2017, 11, 4)
>>>
```

Comment: The integer literal `07` is an [*octal* representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). It's a numbering system with base 8, which means digits go from `0` to `7` (inclusive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer literals on Python 2.x that begin with `0` (and aren't followed by `x` or `b`) are [octal literals](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-specify-hexadecimal-and-octal-integers) (for future compatibility, the `0o` prefix also means an octal literal, and it's the only form accepted in Py3, which rejects *all* "plain" `0` prefixed `int` literals to avoid confusion from people who might try the C octal syntax). Octal only has digits from 0 to 7, so `9` is nonsensical in octal, and `09` is explicitly requesting it be interpreted as octal, thus the error.

In short, don't try to pad out your `int` literals with leading `0`s. It changes the meaning, not just the appearance.

Comment: I wish they had fixed this in Python 3, instead of doubling down and making leading zeros completely invalid without a base specifier character. Ignoring widespread human convention like this is just wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yeah, though I'm sure if they hadn't made that decision, we'd be fielding a dozen questions a day from former C and Python 2 programmers wondering why `os.chmod` with `0777` is setting file permissions to the sticky bit, user read and group/other execute. :-)

Comment: With Python 3 we have that problem today - `0777` is a syntax error. I'd seriously rather deal with the people expecting octal instead of the people expecting ignored leading zeros.